# Software Center is not opening, and sudo apt-get update is not working

Tags: updates, software-center, software-sources, medibuntu

I got the following error when trying to run `sudo apt-get update` in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
predator@kmb:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for predator: 
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
predator@kmb:~$
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the full output from the command ?

Comment: predator@kmb:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for predator: 
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
predator@kmb:~$

Comment: It says that there are an error in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` ...

Comment: Could you include the contents of  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list`

Comment: This is in essence a problem created by yourself by adding the long gone Medibuntu repository, probably by following dome old and outdated guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing it and re-using apt-get update.

Do the following

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
```